# The element has a type "any" implicitly because the expression of type "string" cannot be used to index the type

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a Typescript function in which I am reading the data from a JSON Object depending on the variable, but it shows me an error when accessing the property.

This is my code:

```
let codCountry = 'CO';

let countryId = {
    "CO": "fileIdCo",
    "ES": "fileIdEs",
    "MX": "fileIdMx"
};

let fileId;
for (let getCod of Object.keys(countryId)) {
    if (getCod == codCountry) {
        fileId = countryId[getCod] // error
    }
}
```

This is the error I get in `countryId[getCod]`:

```
The element has an "any" type implicitly because the expression of type "string" cannot be used to index the type "{CO: string; ES: string; MX : string;} ".
   No index signature was found with a parameter of type "string" in type "{CO: string; ES: string; MX: string;}"
```

Comment: Exactly like you asked: If you log countryId.CO you will get 'fileIdCo'.

Comment: Your code works fine on online compiler : https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3x9e67nbj

Comment: @fatimasajjad That’s because it’s a typescript error.

Comment: @Terry That's right, do you know what the problem can be in this case? I can't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from `Object.keys(countryId)` returning `string[]` instead of an array of keys available on `countryId`.  This can be solved by casting what is returned by `Object.keys()` to ensure that it is an array of keys on the object, i.e.:

```
for (let getCod of Object.keys(countryId) as Array<keyof typeof countryId>) {
    if (getCod == codCountry) {
        fileId = countryId[getCod]
    }
}
```

Now you may ask, what does `keyof typeof countryId` actually mean?

- `typeof` returns the type of the `countryId` object
- `keyof` returns all keys available on the *type* of the `countryId` object

[See proof-of-example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAxg9gJgYRgVwHZgE4E8IF4IDkCA8gQNwBQFoksamWAknHhAN4UCQARCdwFwRuAMwCWoZkm4AaLtwCiAZQFCxEuPIDOMuQFkAGipHiQzXQA9uFAL6Vq4CGtNxKwmBggAKGhADm4JBYYYQhiACMAKxAoMAA6AGsQLE1POnRsZgBKCABDTQgAQQwMHKwAHkSsYIgwLAAHEGq0hmYAPmyOTlEQz38wQLx8WEQUdKwOrk4nZlZmjLgAbT7AgF0uaxsgA).

---

If you don't want to perform this manual casting all the time, you can even abstract that into a method that does it for you:

```
function getObjectKeys<T extends object>(obj: T) {
    return Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>;
}
```

Then it's a matter of using `getObjectKeys(YOUR_OBJECT)` instead of using `Object.keys` directly:

```
for (let getCod of getObjectKeys(countryId)) {
    if (getCod == codCountry) {
        fileId = countryId[getCod]
    }
}
```

[See improved example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAxg9gJgYRgVwHZgE4E8IF4IDkCA8gQNwBQFoksamWAknHhAN4UCQARCdwFwRuAMwCWoZkm4AaLtwCiAZQFCxEuPIDOMuQFkAGipHiQzXQA9uFAL6UKwtFDCiYqCAHNwxAEYArEE4A0iBYmgA8ACoQIOZgIKhwmhAwfgFgAHwAFCm+ghEAlOwUECUQGODIGG4+-k4AdADWIZrZfoUAhkkAghgY7VhhTVgwwhBgWAAOICPJfumU1lQ0EGqmcJTCMBgQmcueYEgsM-s1acGhmXTo2Mz5hRycoqOZ+4d4+LCIKNdY91ycq2YrCuDGYAG1XvAALpcRbWIA).

Answer (score 0):

define Interface

```
interface CC {
    CO: string;
    ES: string;
    MX: string;
}
    let cod = 'CO';

    let countryId:<CC> = {
        "CO": "fileIdCo",
        "ES": "fileIdEs",
        "MX": "fileIdMx"
    };
```

Comment: Please remove this answer because it does not help me on this question. I have already updated the question.